# Getting AWS instance details with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm writing my first Ansible playbook to get some instance details from AWS, but I'm unable to get the playbook correct. I'm getting this error: `ERROR! playbooks must be a list of plays`.

Below is my playbook.

```
#get vailable instance details
-name: "Create and attach ebs volumes"

tasks:
        ec2_instance_facts:
         region: us-west-2
         filter :
         "tag:role": PrimaryApplicationInstance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The playbook in ansible follow some syntax and format.

Use below:

```
---
- name: <name of the playbook>
  hosts: <hosts_group>
  tasks:
    - name: <name of the task for reference>
      ec2_instance_facts:
        <module arguments>
```

ansible follows indentation of 2 spaces in yaml format.

Since you are new you can check the syntax of the playbook using below command.

```
ansible-playbook --syntax-check <playbook_file_name>.yml -i inventory

-i --> inventory file where hosts and vars can be defined in the format
<var_name> = <var_value>
```

Comment: thank you seems it was a simple syntax error i got the hang of it and successfully completed my first playbook.

Comment: Great..ansible is quite structured :)